# Moving SVN Repos to New Server

Tags: svn, migration

If I am using svnadmin dump on the first server, running svn 1.6.9 and restoring it on the new server running svn 1.6.11, and the new server will have the same hostname, the URLs will be the same, but the IP address will be different (we are changing the old DNS record to reflect the new IP address):  Will my users have to relocate their working copies?

Are there any other gotchas or caveats, or should this be as easy as it sounds?  Both are Red Hat servers or some flavor of Enterprise Linux.

Answer (score 3):

> Will my users have to relocate their working copies?

That depends on how they are connecting to your repository. If they're connecting via hostname, then no. If they're connecting via IP address, then yes.

> Are there any other gotchas or caveats, or should this be as easy as
>   it sounds? Both are Red Hat servers or some flavor of Enterprise
>   Linux.

It's pretty much that simple (given the details you have). I've done a load of SVN migrations (although none recently) from Ubuntu to Collabnet on Windows and back to Ubuntu or other Linux flavours. Just to be sure though, make sure nobody has any locks on any files as the locks will be lost during the transfer (we had this issue a few times).

Just remember to make sure your auth rules are the same on both boxes; if you're using Apache and `mod_ldap` then it might be as simple as copying your virtualhost directive, but if you're using local users then it could be more complex.

Comment: They are using basic auth

Comment: @GreggLeventhal - well worst case then is that their saved credentials are rejected when they do their next SVN action and they have to re-enter them.

Comment: Lazy Badger reccomends using force uuid to load the repo on the new server, do you concur?  Any other switches I need to use?

Comment: Honestly I didn't do that and as far as I can remember everything worked fine; however there is likely no harm in it.

Answer (score 1):

No, your users will not have to relocate (if they use hostname in repo-URL), but you **must** do not forgot to use `--force-uuid` in load stage (UUID of new repo have to be identical to old) or users will get "UUID mistmatch" error on any operation

Answer (score 1):

I went through the exercise you describe a couple of times without problems. Dump the repository to a file, copy to the new server, load it. Since we were using IP addresses instead of URLs, we had to run

```
$ svn switch --relocate  http://<old-ip>/repositories/path/to/my/project http://<new-ip>/repositories/path/to/my/project
```

for each working copy.